# Twilio "Outgoing Dial" immediately stops with "No Answer"-status

Tags: twilio

i try to connect two phones and it don't work ...

1. I start the first call with php (this works):

   $call = $client->account->calls->create($from, $to, $baseUrl . '?do=connect');
2. I answer the phone and then the callback gives this:

   43664XXXXXXXX

   3. It not even rings it immediately hangup (peep peep peep)

... hmmh, i don't know what to do, log files just show that everything works well but "No Answer" with "--" duration on the "Outgoing Dial".

Comment: Can you share the code that's behind this? It could be any number of things, but it's impossible to say without seeing what you're trying to do with the call.

Answer (score 0):

For trying to debug the main connection, I would start with the following example from the docs:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#make-an-outbound-call

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    "+14155551212", "+14158675309",
    array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
);

echo $call->sid;
```

Note that the `To` number is referenced before the `From` number.